# HTML Paragraph Fragment Id

Tags: html, url

How does http://arstechnica.com/science/2015/01/thin-atmosphere-is-enough-to-keep-many-exoplanets-spinning/#p2 link to the second paragraph of the corresponding page? I know it has something to do with the "#p2" fragment, but the paragraph in question doesn't have an id of "p2".

Using Firefox 31.0 on Windows 7

Comment: you want us to click on this link?

Comment: I guess that would be necessary to answer the question. This is something I just happened to notice using a news reader. Haven't tried to find another example. I don't know how it is working; so creating an example myself is not be possible.

Comment: Change `#p2` to any other number and it will move to the corresponding paragraph. Not sure what the answer is, but a possible answer would be that it finds the first, second, etc paragraph tag depending on what number you enter. Or they have a custom function that handles getting elements by id's. Edit: I can also confirm that the same thing happens on Chrome on Windows 7.

Comment: There is a javascript event listener for onhashchange event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is custom javascript behavior of course. If you are curious check the file `ars.min.ce8deeda61d4ec728127c4f0c17cf83e.js`. It's minimized by you can beautify it and find `Window.onhashchange` event handler which looks something like this:

```
ars.setup_hashchange = function() {
    var a = function() {
    hash = window.location.hash.replace(/^#/, "");
    if (!hash)
        return;
    var a = $("#" + hash + ", *[name=" + hash + "]"), b = hash.match(/^p([0-9]+)(n)?$/), c = hash.match(/^h([0-9]+)$/);
    if (a.length)
        ars.scroll_to(a.first());
    else if (b) {
        var d = $(".article-content > p")[Math.max(0, b[1] - 1)];
        b[2] && (d = $(d).next()), d && ars.scroll_to($(d))
    } else if (c) {
        var e = $(".article-content").find("> h2, > h3, > h4").filter(":not([data-no-jump])")[Math.max(0, c[1] - 1)];
        e && ars.scroll_to($(e))
    }
};
$(window).on("hashchange", a), setTimeout(a, 0)
```

So it takes paragraph index from `location.hash`, then finds corresponding `p` element withing `$(".article-content > p")` collection, and finally scrolls document to it.

Comment: Very cool. I was trying to figure out how to find the document and window event listeners in the FF console when you posted your answer. Seems like a fairly complex solution[to a non-existent?] problem when they could have just added the corresponding id's to the relevant sections of the document.

Comment: I agree. Moreover this solution also will not work in IE<8, while `id="pX"` works fine everywhere. I would simply write 3 lines of code that would set id's dynamically so that you don't even need to do it manually.

Answer (score 0):

This is under `<article>` and the first `<p>` is **`<p class="byline" itemprop="author creator"`** and second `<p>` is the one you are refering to. search for the first `<p>` and you will get the answer.
so `#p2` refering to second `<p>`

Comment: That doesn't seem right. `#p2` is taking me to the paragraph beginning with "Needless to say..." which is actually the third paragraph inside `<article>`.